# How can I accept multiple data types into my input stream?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template< typename T >
void somefunction()
{
   T value;
   cout << " value = ";
   cin >> value;
}
```

Now this seems a bit weird but can we have a function template that accepts multiple
  datatypes( say float and int).

Comment: Please indicate how you would use this, if it were possible.

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by "accepts multiple datatypes". Do you wish to restrict the template function to only float or int? Or do you wish to read one int ánd one float from the input stream?

Comment: @unapersson, the only way he can use is `somefunction<int>()` and so on.

Comment: yes,  wish to restrict the template function to only float or int. but the second opinion is also intersting to me I would like to know about both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you wish to restrict the template function, your best bet is to use [specialization](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.7). Create a generic method which does nothing, or asserts/throws exception, but with specialized implementations for precisely your types. Something like,

```
template< typename T >
void somefunction()
{
    std::cerr << "Not implemented." << std::endl;
}

template< >
void somefunction< float >()
{
   T value;
   cout << " value (float) = ";
   cin >> value;
}

template< >
void somefunction< int >()
{
   int value;
   cout << " value (int) = ";
   cin >> value;
}
```

Of course, when adding more types (double, long, char, etc) this may imply duplicating code. Alternatively you can try to use Boost's [enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/utility/enable_if.html).

The alternative case, where you wish to load two values at once, requires you to present two template arguments:

```
template< typename T1, typename T2 >
void somefunction()
{
   T1 first;
   std::cout << " first value = ";
   std::cin >> first ;

   assert( std::cin.good() );
   T2 second;
   std::cout << " second value = ";
   std::cin >> second ;
}
```

Also make sure in more complex cases that you correctly check the good/fail state of your input stream (cin). For simplicitly, I have used an assert...

Comment: Thanks, @Andre. @Olwaro has also presented a similar answer but this helps me more.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to restrict the template to int and float, you will have to specialize your template :

```
template< typename T >
void somefunction()
{
   // May be throw std::bad_typeid
};

template<>
void somefunction<int>()
{
   int value;
   cout << " int value = ";
   cin >> value;
};

template<>
void somefunction<float>()
{
   float value;
   cout << " float value = ";
   cin >> value;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** it is possible. If the data type supports `operator >>` (and `operator <<` if you want to print it).

Comment: Is it possible to give any example here